# $parse:lexerr thrown when creating an html element containing ng-click and a String link as parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an infinite scroll of a list view and creating new list elements with `angular.element()`. 
Every list element has a `ng-click` property and in the function couple of parameters are being passed, one of which is a link passed as string. Therefore angular throws a syntax err because of a colon symbol in the `"http:"`substring. Does anyone know how can I go around this problem? I tried different ways to fix it but still couldn't manage to resolve it.

**This is how I create the element**

```
let newPresentationDiv = angular.element("<div role='presentation' ng-click='openArticle("+ art.source +", "+ art.id +", "+ art.image +", " + art.title +");'></div>")
$compile(newPresentationDiv)($scope)
```

**This is the created HTML:**

```
<div role="presentation" ng-click="openArticle(GI, https://www.gesundheitsinformation.de/eierstockzysten-ovarialzysten.2638.de.atom, null, Eierstockzysten (Ovarialzysten));" class="ng-scope"></div>
```

**This is the Error I am getting**

```
Syntax Error: Token ':' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 22 of
the expression [openArticle(GI, https://www.gesundheitsinformation.de/eierstockzysten-ova..., null, Eierstockzysten (Ovarialzysten))]  
starting at [://www.gesundheitsinformation.de/eierstockzysten-ovarialzysten.2638.de.atom, null, Eierstockzysten (Ovarialzysten].
```

I tried to put the link in `" "` but it didn't work. 
Also I tried to remove the `http://` part of the string but I get errors for other characters in the string and I would prefer not to manipulate the link itself.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you in advance :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is issue in the way you are creating template. You need to put `'` to render it as string value.

```
<div role="presentation" ng-click="openArticle('GI', 'https://www.gesundheitsinformation.de/eierstockzysten-ovarialzysten.2638.de.atom, null, Eierstockzysten (Ovarialzysten)');" class="ng-scope">Click me</div>
```

Here is the [plunkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/aasTvLIjOjLNMshfbOr9?p=preview)

Try

```
let newPresentationDiv = angular.element("<div role='presentation' ng-click=\"openArticle('"+ art.source +"', '"+ art.id +"', '"+ art.image +"', '" + art.title +"')\"></div>")
```

Comment: Yup, it worked! I tried before to put the properties in ' but the \" in  ng-click=\"openArticle I was always missing and this was breaking the whole html element..
Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @VLazzarova : Cheers :)